# suma a la derecha e izquierda de la matriz principal

Tags: r

tengo una base que es tipo matriz, necesito hallar con el programa r una columna que muestre la diagonal principal, otra columna que muestre la suma para cada fila de los datos de la derecha e izquierda de la diagonal principal. adjunto como quedaría el resultado con las sumas en colores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Oscar, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, resuélvanlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema.

Answer (score -2):

Te dejo algunas nociones que podrían ayudarte a resolver el problema que tienes:

Usa la función `diag()` de R. Con ella obtendras la diagonal pincipal de la matriz.

```
# Obtener la diagonal principal
diagonal <- diag(mat)
```

Luego puedes crear una matriz que indique si un elemento está o no a la derecha de la diagonal. Con `apply()` aplicas la función suma a cada fila de la matriz

```
derecha_diagonal <- col(matriz) > row(matriz)
fila_suma <- apply(matriz[derecha_diagonal], 1, sum)
```

Si lees un poco la documentación respecto a estas funciones, podrás resolver tu problema con facilidad. Ánimo!